# Get ipv4 address of visitors in http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler hosted

Tags: python, ip-address, basehttprequesthandler

When hosting a simple `http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler` server from Python, I would like to get the ip address of anyone accessing my server. I looked around, and I found solutions in Java and C, but nothing in Python. When I tried to convert the solutions in either language, they would not work. The `GetIp` from Java was not a part of the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` class, nor was the `UserHostName` from C. I also am not serving from `Flask`, `bottle`, or any other serving platform, so I cannot use any of their methods. How would I do this?

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Comment: And please don't artificially "tag" your titles. Use the real tags that Stack Overflow provides.

Comment: In this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, it said to be as descriptive as possible in your titles, so I tried to let the users know they were getting into a question about Python, because this is a topic that could be problematic across multiple languages. But yes, I will admit that I was wrong with the [solved] in the answer.

Comment: Again, that's what _actual tags_ are for. You correctly included the [tag:python] tag; don't make up some tagging format to cram into your title.

Answer (score 2):

There is subclass, `request` that is part of the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` class, and inside it is are functions that will tell you ip addresses of your server, and the machines accessing it. Add this to your `do_GET` function:
`self.request.getpeername()`

This will return a tuple of the form:

```
(their ipv4 address, their port)
```